# Listing image files from a directory for SlidesJS to make into a slider on a Wordpress website.

Tags: php, wordpress, image

So, I've got the Slides JS correctly set-up but I want to create a PHP code to list files from a directory, if possible by modified date first.

This is the code that I've got so far:

```
<div id="slides">
<div class="slides_container">
<?php
$directory = "/wp-content/themes/1/img/";

$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

$imgs = '';

foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }

foreach ($imgs as $img) {

    echo "<div>
            <img src='$img' />
          </div> ";
}
?>  
</div>
</div>
```

Which from my understanding should list the .jpg images in the directory as:

```
<div>
  <img src="image_src_here.jpg" />
</div>
```

But it's not listing anything - do i need to add this as a function to wordpress?

Secondly, how can I list the images by modified date, is this possible?

URL: msc-media.co.uk

Comment: Any reason for the double loop? Why assign your list of files straight to `$imgs`. Also are you sure using the correct link to the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting a valid filepath, and your second loop is unnecessary. Do something like this:

```
<?php
$directory = ABSPATH."wp-content/themes/1/img/";
$images = glob($directory."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image)
{
    $src = str_replace(ABSPATH, site_url('/'), $image);
    $imgs[] = $src;
    echo '<div><img src="'.$src.'" /></div>';
}
?>
```